# Windows text editor that can encode URL for all the non-ASCII characters

Tags: windows, text-editor, url

I'm looking for a Windows text editor featuring URL encode for all the non-ASCII characters

For example, when encoding the following string:

[https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:出窓ぬいぐるみ_2016_(25772941925).jpg](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:%E5%87%BA%E7%AA%93%E3%81%AC%E3%81%84%E3%81%90%E3%82%8B%E3%81%BF_2016_(25772941925).jpg)

the result should be this:

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:%E5%87%BA%E7%AA%93%E3%81%AC%E3%81%84%E3%81%90%E3%82%8B%E3%81%BF_2016_(25772941925).jpg

(this is the URL the Chrome gives you when you copy the page location in te clipboard)

I'm using Notepad2 but it doesn't encode the non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Maybe do it outside of the editor - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34447793/does-windows-have-any-built-in-utility-to-encode-decode-url

Answer (score 3):

[Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) has a plugin available called **MIME Tools** which has URL encode and decode functions.  It even has a "Full URL Encode" which encodes even the ASCII characters.

Answer (score 2):

**[CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/)** editor can do it with plugin "Encode".

- menu Plugins/ AddonManager/ Install, select plugin "Encode"
- select entire URL with unicode chars
- call plugin: Plugins/ Encode/ URL Encode

It replaces URL to encoded.